# Annotation a Map containig a non-entity class in JPA

Tags: java, jpa

Is it possible to use a map with a non-entity class in JPA? If yes, how should it be annotated correctly?

```
@Entity
class A {

   @HowShouldIAnnotateThis?
   private Map<B, Integer> myMap = new HashMap<B, Integer>();

}

@Entity
class B {
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this with JPA 1.0. Some implementations provide proprietary extensions (such as EclipseLink's [`@BasicMap`](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Using_EclipseLink_JPA_Extensions_(ELUG)#How_to_Use_the_.40BasicMap_Annotation)) which you could use if you don't mind coupling your application to the given JPA provider.

JPA 2.0 will provide similar functionality with `@ElementCollection`.